# Game of 6 players

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, menu

I want the user to choose two players from a menu of 6 players, these players will play a game of tennis.

I tried making a menu with submenues but it just gets complicated and messy.

```
def player1():
    print("You chose player 1, please choose another player")
def player2():
    print("You chose player 2, please choose another player")
def player3():
    print("You chose player 3, please choose another player")
def player4():
    print("You chose player 4, please choose another player")
def player5():
    print("You chose player 5, please choose another player")
def player6():
    print("You chose player 6, please choose another player")


Player_select = {
    1: player1,
    2: player2,
    3: player3,
    4: player4,
    5: player5,
    6: player6
}

Selection = 0


while (Selection != 7):
     print("1. player1")
     print("2. player2")
     print("3. player3")
     print("4. player4")
     print("5. player5")
     print("6. player6")
     print("7. Quit")
     Selection = int(input("Please choose two players: "))
     if (Selection >= 0) and (Selection < 7):
         Player_select[Selection]()
     Selection = Selection - 1
```

The results is that the while loop continues longer then i want to. I want the user to choose two players meaning two iterations? also I want the player the user chooses to not appear anymore as a choice in the second iteration.

Comment: Also, you have 6 player functions that all do pretty much the same thing. Why not give the player number as argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def player1():
    print("You chose player 1, please choose another player")
def player2():
    print("You chose player 2, please choose another player")
def player3():
    print("You chose player 3, please choose another player")
def player4():
    print("You chose player 4, please choose another player")
def player5():
    print("You chose player 5, please choose another player")
def player6():
    print("You chose player 6, please choose another player")


Player_select = {
    1: player1,
    2: player2,
    3: player3,
    4: player4,
    5: player5,
    6: player6
}

Selection = 0

count = 0
while (count < 2):
    count += 1
    for k in Player_select:
        print(str(k) +". player"+str(k))
    Selection = int(input("Please choose two players: "))
    if (Selection >= 0) and (Selection < 7):
        Player_select[Selection]()
        del Player_select[Selection]
```

This deletes the player from the dictionary once selected. Can you tell me why you decremented the Selection by 1 at the end of the while loop? If I type 7 to exit, the loop does 7 - 1 and so doesn't exit.

Comment: thanks!! and if I want my game to continue and not exit out after the user chooses 2 players? Silly mistake by me, forgot to change smh

Comment: Do you want to choose more than two players? Or do something else in the while loop?

Comment: No. Basically I have a menu, when I press alternative 1 it starts a "New game" which continues to this part. Here the user chooses between 2 players. After this the user will also choose who won the game between these 2 players. Then the scores will update in my textfile.

Comment: once you have chosen two players, it will exit the while loop, and go to the next line in your python script. So to continue the game you want to write some more code underneath the loop?

Comment: yes, so when i've chosen two players I will need to exit out of the while loop and continue the script because the user needs to choose who wins the game between the 2 players. Where I get confused is that all this works within a submenu, so I don't know where to continue the script?

Comment: I'm not familiar with submenus sorry

Comment: No worries. Just one more thought though, don't I have to tell what each player's (1-6) attributes are? Each player has it's own attributes and i have written those in a textfile. And I made a list of players from the stuff in my textfile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice short answer with a while-loop:

```
players = ["player1", "player2", 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6']


def print_player(x):
    print("You chose player:", str(x), "-", players[x-1])


for id, player in enumerate(players, 1):
    print(str(id) + '. ' + player)


chosen_players = []
while len(chosen_players) != 2:
    selection = int(input("Please choose a player: "))
    if selection in range(1, len(players)):
        chosen_players.append(selection)
        print_player(selection)
    else:
        print('Invalid number, choose again')

print('Nice you selected two players:')
print([players[x-1] for x in chosen_players])
```

Comment: How do I then choose who will win the game if I use this while loop?

Comment: your original question doesn't mention anything about winning the game, but just selection.
How should I know who will win the game?
If you want to continue with the program just add new lines at the end